PHP within HTML <SERVER SIDE - NOT BROWSER SIDE>
Info: Raspberry pi 4 - apache running, php installed. All works well.
The index html file shows the images etc. and auto refreshes based on some parameters i.e. if it sees a file called file_change.txt it should delete that file and then do a refresh of the page. So, all of this code is server side. I have a maintenance html page that I change an image from, this in turn writes out the file_change.txt file, copies the filename from the drop down menu over the top of default.jpg that resides in the images directory  and thus, the server side index file should do a refresh when finding the 'flag' file (file_change.txt) , delete that file and reload the index.html, thus, displaying the new image.
Right now the deletion does not work. The refresh is fine, it refreshes and displays the new image (coded so no matter what new image I pick, it writes it back out to the server as default.jpg hence, the html code to refresh just grabs the same default.jpg but displays it as a new image)
I have an index.html file that has <?php code within it. I have a file called file_change.txt within the  images directory called file_change.txt - one level higher/lower (depending on how you look at it :) ) than where the index.html resides.
In the HTML code, I am executing the following (I can run a php file from the command line of the server that removes the file): Here is the code (in the main <body> of the html file:
<?php
                $file_path = '/var/www/html/images/file_change.txt';

                if (file_exists($file_path)) {
                        // Delete the file
                        unlink($file_path);
                        echo "The file '$file_path' has been deleted.";
                } else {
                        echo "The file '$file_path' does not exist.";
                }
        ?>

This code does not run.
I can do a php -version as follows:
/var/www/html $ php -versionPHP 8.3.12 (cli) (built: Sep 27 2024 04:03:53) (NTS)Copyright (c) The PHP GroupZend Engine v4.3.12, Copyright (c) Zend Technologieswith Zend OPcache v8.3.12, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

For some reason this does not work in the html doc.
If I run php remove.php (just a script with same php commands, in the same directory as the index.html file, I get this:
/var/www/html $ php remove.phpThe file '/var/www/html/images/file_change.txt' has been deleted.<hidden server name>:/var/www/html $

This deletes the file. So I know php is working.
So the php works on the local server. But, when running from the html page that is also on the local server (the html page runs locally, nothing to do with any browser interaction) it does not remove the file.
I am a little confused why I can run php remove.php from the same directory that the index.html resides in and it can delete the file but the <?php code within the html file cannot.
Any thoughts? I have googled the heck out of this and maybe I have just looked too much and missed the obvious but would appreciate some input.
I also have a strange issue where calling a very generic blah.php file from a browser also does not work - just a blank screen - does not display a simple 'hello world' but php is installed and running as described above.

<?php is not magic text, the server need to be configured to run .html files through the PHP interpreter. The magic being that the PHP interpreter simply ignores anything outside of <?php ... ?>. That said, it would be simpler to change the filename to .php.

Also, it's generally not good form to ask multiple questions in a single SO post, but the latter is likely a White Screen Of Death [WSOD] which is the result of an error occurring while having error reporting disabled.

I have tried everything from changing index.html to index.php etc. One thing I forgot to mention is that on boot-up of the PI, chromium-browser is automatically called and fires off the web page. This is a hands off application that has nodejs checking for a file, renaming it to default.jpg and then the meta refresh within the index.html just loads the default.jpg image after a time period. I want to avoid it 'refreshing' constantly, I want it to see a flag set, remove the flag and then refresh. If there is no flag, do not refresh.

@sammitch - apologies, I was not intending to ask multiple questions, more 'explaining more in-depth' about what I was trying to achieve within the original post. brain fried from 7am onwards while working on this and other coding that I was doing.

If the server cofnig is not set to run HTML/HTM as PHP then PHP code will not run -- test this with <?php echo "hello I am PHP"; >.   If the PHP block is not in the <body> the echo might happen but not be visible.   If you do not have errors and warnings enabled while testing (not for production use) you will not see things like warnings for undefined variables from typos and errors like access denied because the PHP/webserver user and the file owner are different.  Browser caching can show you an old view of a page.

Also add a try{} catch() Block around your Code, catch Error and Exception and echo them, so you know, whats wrong.

@WolfgangBlessen there's no need for that. Php will do that for you automatically if you enable error reporting.

Found my error guys. Thanks for your input. I did not know I had to sudo apt install -y libapache2-mod-php8.3 also. I thought just installing PHP would be enough.

Ah yeah, that's a bit which actually links Apache and PHP together. Without that, Apache doesn't know anything about PHP. Glad you fixed it
